# <p:growl/> wont show message when using PrimeFaces.MonitorDownload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download, monitor, growl

I am using PrimeFaces.Monitordownload function to monitor the progress of file download. First the file is created then downloaded. If anything goes wrong, a error file is created and downloaded with streamed content instead of real file. This is fine and works well. The problem occurs when I want to add a error message along with the error file. I have no idea how to update my growl.

When using PrimeFaces.monitorDownload, I need to set `ajax=false`. Could this be part of my problem?

I have tried multiple things, like setting `update="growl"` on the `p:commandButton`, `autoUpdate=true` on the growl itself, but nothing. I might be doing something wrong in my backing bean, but don't think so.

Here is my relevant Java code:

```
boolean fileCreated = processor.start();

    if(fileCreated){
        File xlsfile = new File(filePath);
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(xlsfile);
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "file/xlsx", fileName);
        return file;
    }else{
        fileName = fileName.replace(".xlsx", ".txt");
        filePath = rootPath + fileName;
        File xlsfile = new File(filePath);
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(xlsfile);
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "file/txt", fileName);
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Something went wrong!", "Please send an email to servicedesk and alert the administrators of this page!");
        FacesContext.addMessage(null, message);
        return file;
    }
```

And my xhtml:

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"
                footer="Creating file. It might take up to 30 minutes, depending on the file size."
                draggable="true" closable="false" resizable="false">
                <p:graphicImage name="/bigLoader.gif"
                    style="margin-left :auto; margin-right:3.7cm;" />
</p:dialog>

<p:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="submit" ajax="false"
                        disabled="#{controllerBean.selectedBrands.size() lt 1}"
                        styleClass="btn btn-default"
                        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{controllerBean.file}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Add brand" styleClass="btn btn-default"
                        action="#{controllerBean.addBrand()}"
                        update=":first:brands: :first:tableGroup: :first:submitBtn:">
</p:commandButton>
```

I'm using Mojarra 2.2, Primefaces 5.3.
Any help  much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Filedownload is a non-ajax request, so the update attribute won't do anything.

I think you don't need to download a fake/blank file in the case of an error. You should just present the user an error msg.

I recommend that you create 2 steps to download, as your file generation process seems too slow:

First step (ajax) generates the file and saves it on the backing bean (if successful). If the generation fails, then present error message.

If the file was successfully generated (fileCreated=true), enable the download button, which will just download the generated file (ajax=false).

Remember to nullify the file variable after download to free memory.

Additionally, if you have the time, you could put a progressBar for the generation process...

Comment: Sorry, but that would't do. It is not a blank error file. It contains the exception and the message i wanted to display, tells the user to include that textfile in the ticket they create when and if something goes wrong. I solved it myself though. Here is how i didi it, if any one else finds themselves in this situation:

I added a <p:remoteCommand tag. Created a method that checks if the error file exits, and update the growl tag.

Then, in PFs start stop function, i just added the name for the premoteCommand right after the stop function is called. Simple and clean. :) thanks though!